# Filtering Dataframe Results Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with filtering dataframe results set based on multiple conditions and would appreciate your help on the case below.

In the example below I would like to filter based on two conditions in dataframe:

1. Column "Condition 1" = 1
2. Column "Condition 2" = 0

In the code I use the following logic to filter the results with "filt" variable:

```
filt = (df["Condition 1"] )== 1 & (df["Condition 2"] == 0)
```

Unfortunately, the two-condition filter does not yield the desired results. In fact, neither conditions 1 nor 2 are met in the output.

```
print(df.loc[filt, "Condition 3"])
```

An alternative approach that worked but I would like to avoid is to create a third condition where *"Condition 1" - "Condition 2" = 1* and base a filter on it. This would look as follows:

```
filt2 = df["Condition 3"] == 1

print(df.loc[filt2, "Condition 3"])
```

Notice that in this case there is only one condition in the filter ("filt2") which eventually produces the expected results.

My questions are:

1. Is there a reason that the multiple (two) filters do not work in my example, while the single condition filter does? Is there something I am overlooking in the code?
2. Are there better and simpler solutions to the alternative approach used with creating a third condition?

PS: The code below on "filt" would also produce the expected results.

```
filt = df["Condition 1"] - df["Condition 2"] == 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter like this:

```
filt = df[(df["Condition 1"] == 1) & (df["Condition 2"] == 0)]
```

filt dataframe will contain the desired result

Comment: Thank you gtomer. 

Is there something that we are missing and could produce "Cannot index with multidimensional key" type of error?



filt2 = df[(df["Condition 1"] == 1) & (df["Condition 2"] == 0)]

print(df.loc[filt2])

Comment: [Screenshot of the error](https://imgur.com/JII5Hnw)

Comment: what are you trying to print at line 38?

Comment: At line 38 I am trying to print the filtered results based on the modified filter you provided using two conditions ("filt2"). Exampe here for the single-condition"filt" at line 39: [Screenshot lines 38 and 39](https://imgur.com/Y6LR0tb)

Comment: The new dataframe 'filt' contains the results already. try print (filt)

Comment: That is correct, "filt" would to the job and produce the expected results. However, I would like to base the dataframe on "filt2" which uses two conditions and an AND clause. How could we avoid the "multidimentional key" error while we base the dataframe on "filt2" ?

Comment: "filt2 = (df["Condition 1"] == 1) & (df["Condition 2"] == 0)" produces the expected result. It seems to be the paranthesеs.